# How to position the NavigationBar x pixels from the top

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to position the UINavigationBar x pixels from the top. Is this possible? Here is a screenshot of the desired result.

[image: img]

To clarify, I want the NavigationBar to be positioned in the orange area. The area black area above is an ARKit view running and should not be covered by anything.

Is this even possible?

I've tried setting the NavigationBar frame and messing around with the positionForBar property. Nothing have an effect, the NavigationBar is always rendered at the top. One thing that add is that this solution, if there is any, has to be done in code and not in storyboard.

Comment: Not really sure if its the best solution but you can probably achieve this using `View Containment` [here](https://medium.com/appcoda-tutorials/avoiding-massive-view-controller-using-containment-child-view-controller-alfian-losari-98429158faf5) is a reference for this topic

Answer (score 0):

Just create a constraint from the Top Safe Area Guide's bottom to your view...?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You have said it, you changed the frame but nothing happened as you don't have the ability to change(Move or resize) the UINavigationController's navigation bar. To solve this problem you have to write your own view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the navigation bar’s transform.

i.e.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: yourTopInset)
```